# request.IsAuthenticated not working with custom membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, membership

My login is..at controller

```
 MemberShipProvider objMProvider = new MemberShipProvider();
        var abc =RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var checkVal = objMProvider.ValidateUser(m.username, m.password);
            if (checkVal == true)
            {
                Session["User"] = m.username;
                TempData["userName"] = m.username;
                //IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl("~/User_Dashboard.aspx");
               abc=RedirectToAction("Dashboard","User");
            }
            else if (checkVal == false)
            {
                abc = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                return abc;
            }
        }
```

my webconfig membership setting...

```
 <system.web>
<membership defaultProvider="MemberShipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MemberShipProvider" type="FndooMvc.Models.Common.MemberShipProvider"
         connectionStringName="mycon"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

my custom membership provider logincheck code is 
`public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return objLogin.IsValid(username,password) == true ? true : false;
        }`
i used flat login code then i decided to use custom membership as per demand. help me use this identity and principle feature with this custom membership 
for now i want to know why my request.IsAuthenicated

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/identity) :

The ASP.NET Identity system is designed to replace the previous ASP.NET Membership and Simple Membership systems. It includes profile support, OAuth integration, works with OWIN, and is included with the ASP.NET templates shipped with Visual Studio 2013.

and if you want a good article in [identity and principle feature](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity)

Comment: thats great information ,but i need time to understand to impliment this,BTW sample projects from your provided link does not run has tonns of errors

Comment: you have to install the missed packages, use the Package Manager Console by executing one by one:
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin
Install-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package Antlr
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework -Pre
... do this for all the missed references in References in the solution explorer

Comment: this project didnot have a sln file so i opened it by browsing folder and opened as a website installed all things you mentioned builds sucessfully but it gives me an error 
ie HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: They have changed a lot, I am sorry below link is old revision:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2umJbDOzaxYcVZGbVAtWUJOUVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you so much sir , i am able to run this project it would be great to learn this, at first i downloaded everything that was missng but after installation igave me strange errors then i deleted everything and clicked on just restore packege and then upgraded asp.net mvc and its working well, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

i needed this code block in global config in authenticate request event.

```
 HttpCookie authCookie =Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket =
                                        FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
            GenericPrincipal userPrincipal =
                             new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name),
                                                  roles);
            Context.User = userPrincipal;
        }
```

now request.isAuthenticated works.

how ever i am gonna change this provider and use as Hboubati suggested.